# What does a web-based framework scalable?

Tags: frameworks, scalability

thanks you very much in advance.

First of all, I conceive scalability as the ability to design a system that doest not change when the demand of its services, whatever they are, increases considerably. May you need more hardware (vertically or horizontally0? Fine, add it at your leisure because the system is prepared and has been designed to cope with it.

My question is simple to ask but presumably very complex to answer. I would like to know what you I look at in a framework to make sure it will scale accordingly, both in number of hits and number of sessions running simultaneously.

This question is not about technology nor a particular framework at all, it is more a theoretical question.

I know that depend very much on having a good database design and a proper hardware behind with replication, etc... Let's assume that this all exists, however yet my framework must meet some criteria, what?

- Provide a memcache?
- Ability to run across multiple machines (at the web server level) and use many replicated databases? But what is in the software that makes that possible?
- etc...

Please, let's not relate the answers with any particular programming language or technology behind.

Thanks again,

D.

Comment: Good scalability is more a property of application design and not of any framework or programming language in general. It all depends upon the overall architecture of your site, then the inherent hardware on which you're deploying your code on. During the inception phases of one of my projects, I had evaluated web frameworks from many languages - parameters were performance, scaling, design, learning curve, extensibility, flexibility, maintainability. I came to the conclusion that most modern web-based frameworks more-or-less lend themselves very well to scaling.

Comment: I'm glad that one of the questions here echoes my viewpoint - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222970/scalability-on-the-web

Comment: Thanks. Well it is not the same, it is more oriented to technologies. It is ore a general question. A web application that is over a framework means that a framework has something to say about scalability. We are outsourcing our development with a company that has got an in-house framework, hence my question.

Comment: This question belongs to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think scalability depends most of all on the use case: do you expect huge amounts of data, then you should focus on the database, if it's about traffic, focus on the server, is it about adding new features, focus on your data-model and the framework you are using...

Comparing a microposts-service like Twitter to a university website or a webservice like GoogleDocs you will find quite different requirements.

Comment: Thanks. That's is a very good one. However given that our development is going to be over an in-house framework, this may be the weak point that is why I am oriented the question toward what a framework can do to help scalability.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the common notion of scalability is the ability of a software to improve in throughput or capacity if more hardware resources are added (CPUs, memory, bandwidth etc).
Software that does not improve in increased resources is not scalable.
Getting out of the definitions, I think your question is related to evaluation of frameworks you are planning to introduce to your implementation that may affect your software's ability to scale.
IMHO the most important factor to evaluate when introducing a framework is to see if there is hidden serialization in it (that serialization in effects transfers to/affects your software)
So if you introduce a framework that introduces serialization in your application that can affect your ability to scale.
How to evaluate?

1. Careful source code inspection (if open source)
2. Are there any performance guarantees offered by those that build the
   framework?
3. Do measurements yourself to see how introducing this framework
   affects your performance and replace if not satisfied

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by serialization please? Something like sending objects from the client to the server (like Java for example)? AFAIR, we will be sending data across using JSON.

Comment: @user1593139:No, I mean doing things serially and not concurrent.So your app from a highly concurrent multithreaded becomes serial

Comment: oh I see, well it is a web so the web server by nature will make them happen concurrently. I mean we do not have any task that must be done in the background through multiple threads because it is very long and will cause hundred of request to be queued.

Comment: @user1593139: certain database locking could make multiple requests to need to be handled serially.

Comment: @LieRyan:There is always somewhere that you would need to do something sequentially.The difference is the granularity level and how optimal something is done

Comment: @user384706: true, but the difference is whether such locking are truly necessary, and whether it's possible to override the framework when you know the framework precaution is unnecessary.

Comment: Well the site is all about settling auctions where people can bid at certain assets. From that description, one could think that would be a potential problem but we are handling that by using row-locking level, that is many reads can happen over the same table son long as the targeted rows are different. A this is exactly how it will be. However I am not pointing at such low level, I Just want to understand the theoretical weaknesses as a rule of thumb that could bring forward the scalability problem