# what does a web-based framework perform well?

Tags: performance, frameworks

thanks in advance.

Somewhere else I asked the same question but about scalability. Please let's not confuse both terms. I'd really like to understand what particular parameters I should look at when assessing if a framework performs acceptably.

I mean parameters such not over-querying the database for simple tasks just because the ORM above is not very well written, etc... Please let's try to answer this question without diving into a particular technology.

Lastly, let's assume that the underlying hardware is any that allow you to perform well, that is to say, there is no hardware bottleneck. I don't want a software that uses a cannon to kill mosquitos :).

Thanks again.

Comment: What's the difference with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11921092/what-does-a-web-based-framework-scalable/11921274#11921274?

Comment: Huge difference. That one is about scalability, this one is about performance :). They are two different concepts.

Comment: This question is more suited to Programmers SE as it is a management issue and not a programming

Answer (score 0):

> I mean parameters such not over-querying the database for simple tasks
>   just because the ORM above is not very well written, etc... Please
>   let's try to answer this question without diving into a particular
>   technology.

Succesfull ORM technologies are not under-performant. But if your web application is extremely simple (you don't define the scope of your question) then introducing a robust ORM that would be an overkill. Do a DAO pattern yourself instead.

Finally you can always do test measurements yourself to evaluate if the performance suits you

Comment: Thanks. WEll that is one of my main worries. We are outsourcing the development and the company has got their own framework based on php hence my worry. Still the ORM is one of the parameters but surely there are others such as the session handling, how requests are pass on the controllers, etc...

Comment: @user1593139:The way you describe this, it is a management decision and not a techical one.If you are outsourcing and others are doing the dev, then I guess there are some specs concerning the performance etc.Otherwise why are you outsourcing if they are cheap but do not meet your requirements?Perhaps this question is more suited to Programmers SE

Comment: Thanks. Well I don't know whether they meet the requirements or not. That decision was made way before I got in the company :). I am a developer and not a manager, although I won't be participating in the development. I have got my own concerns but want to hear from other fellows that have far more experience than me in this particular case.

Comment: @user1593139:IMHO if you are a developer, then you should express your concerns to your managers who got this decision.Perhaps from their point of view they only care is the cost.

Comment: ha ha ha. You named it. We will have to cope anyway with what we have got as they signed the contract. However I will do my job independently whether they like hearing what I am going to say or not.

Comment: @user1593139:I still think that you are viewing this the wrong way.This is not a technical issue anymore but a managerial one.If you are just a developer you can only express your concerns and do your best on your part.You should ask this question (but from the managerial angle to Programmers SE) intead

Comment: Well I just need to express my concerns. What the management does with it is down to them but I do need to express those concerns and that is what I trying to find out.